# Preserve Elm compiler error colors when running Elm app through Brunch

Tags: compiler-errors, elm, brunch

I'm writing an **Elm** app using **Brunch** for compilation and hot-reloading, and while **elm-reactor** has very nice error color styles, when Brunch displays compiler errors, they're in all green and harder to read. Is there a way to tell Brunch to preserve the colors set by the elm compiler?